# Adding a custom block cipher to Node JS?

Tags: openssl, node.js

I have a modified version of openssl with a custom TLS cipher that I am testing. How would I use it in Node JS?

I have pointed the modified version of openssl to Node JS using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I have tried specifying the custom TLS cipher using the `--tls-cipher-list` option to no avail. However I can list it from the `openssl ciphers` command.

Here is the command:

```
$ node --tls-cipher-list="ECDHE-ECDSA-SPECK256-SHA256" index.js --verbose
```

And output:

```
Error [ERR_SOCKET_CLOSED]: Socket is closed
at TLSSocket.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:752:18)
at TLSSocket.connect (net.js:742:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:275:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:187:15)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1147:10)

Error: 1996407328:error:141640B5:SSL routines:tls_construct_client_hello:no 
ciphers available:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:800:

at TLSSocket._start (_tls_wrap.js:655:16)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:275:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:187:15)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1147:10)
```

Comment: Have you checked, that the custom library and not the original one is actually loaded (for example check with strace)? And what exactly does *"... to no avail"* mean - any error messages, different behavior than expected or what?

Comment: Thanks for dealing with the second part of my comment. What about the first part too: *"Have you checked, that the custom library and not the original one is actually loaded (for example check with strace)?"* You might also try `lsof -np pid` to  see which libraries are actually use by a running binary.